# How to delete the clearfix div of a field (fivestar module)

Tags: 7, theming, rating

I'm using Drupal 7 and [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar).

The module fivestar implements systematically a div in the fields of type "fivestar", what gives : `<div class="clearfix">fivestar value</div>`.

I would want to delete this div to have only the value.

I saw that she was implemented at the level of fivestar.module.

I tried a template preprocess but unsuccessfully :

```
 function THEME_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  if ($element['#field_name'] == 'field_NAME') {
    $variables['items'][0]['#prefix'] = '';
    $variables['items'][0]['#suffix'] = '';
  }
}
```

Would you have a solution ?

Comment: I not too sure what you mean. How about use CSS to remove it? Example: .clearfix{display:none;}

Comment: I want to remove the markup

Comment: Is there any sample code?

Comment: @learnallskill I edited my question. I have just noticed that this div was implemented by the module fivestar

Comment: very sorry. Am I right to say you only want to delete the class clearfix?

Comment: @learnallskill No ;) I want to delete the div completely, but not the contents. Pass of `<div class="clearfix">fivestar value</div>` to `fivestar value`.

Comment: maybe can use jquery. example: $( ".clearfix" ).remove();